# Old edits on old closed posts now triggering reopen votes?

Tags: bug, status-completed, status-bydesign

Lately we've been getting a number of [re-open candidates](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/history). Some of were last active as far back as two years. In some cases, the last edit that was made to them is what's referenced as the reason it's been added as a re-open review task, even when the last edit was more than a year ago.

For example, [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20853/how-to-learn-game-graphic-design-for-non-artist) was last active more than a year ago. But it showed up on the [review queue today](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/18243). It hasn't been touched in a long time, yet it showed up for re-opening.

Other strangeness is stuff like the re-open queue showing 30+ items to review, then only 3 items are reviewed before you're done and the review queue is empty.

Also, questions are showing up multiple times over the course of a few days:

[A* Search in games](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56085/a-search-in-games)

Showed up [two days ago](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/18056), [today](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/18133) AND [back in May](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/15123). All were triggered by the same revision from three months ago.

So, all kinds of bugs here.

Answer (score 1):

That old edits make questions come up in the reopen queue is by design. If a question has been edited after being closed, it is now eligible for reopening.

In regards to questions showing up multiple times - this has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the multiple issue. I wasn't aware the reopen vote after edit was going to happen retroactively. If that's the case, it seems like there should be a limit on how far back that goes. Not as much for this site, but I imagine SO will be dealing with retroactive reopens for a while. Anyway, thanks for your quick work.